# What are the valid values of the expression (uninitialized_bool ? 1 : 2)?

Tags: c++, initialization

What is the set of valid outputs for the following, according to the standard?

```
bool x;
cout << (x ? 1 : 2);
```

edit: **unknown(google)** has got it. In gcc my code was crashing because of `sprite.setFrame(isPressed ? 0 : 1)` with the conditional returning 28!

Comment: It it a bad practice to use the uninitialized variable. All variables should be initialized as soon as it is declared.

Comment: You could have tried confirming your suspicions with an assert:
bool x;
assert(x == true||x == false);
cout << (x ? 1 : 2);

Comment: For `isPressed ? 0 : 1`, GCC can just do an `isPressed ^ 1` internally. So `isPressed` in your code probably had the bit-pattern representing `29` and GCC's `^ 1` operation made a 28 out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using a bool value in ways described
>   by This Standard as "undefined" such
>   as by examining the value of an
>   unitialized automatic variable, might
>   cause it to behave as it is neither
>   true or false.

Welcome to the world of undefined behaviour. But first, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If x is uninitialized, it can be both true or false. So the valid outputs are 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

["++?????++ Out of Cheese Error. Redo From Start."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(Discworld))

Comment: Pratchett knows whereof he speaks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a uninitialised variable is undefined.So anything can happen

Comment: Undefined behavior, or just an undefined value? Can you quote the standard?

Comment: I'm not sure now if it's "undefined" or "unspecified". If it has an "unspecified" value, then it can be either true or false and so you can get 1 and 2. If behaviour is "undefined", then yes anything could happen.

Comment: I mean, maybe the variable is _required_ by the standard to have some value (_any_ value) belonging, of course, to its possible set of values. So you can make a C++-standard-compliant compiler that after "int i; cout << i;"gives you "88", but not one that crashes.

Comment: well, not ANYTHING can happen. I mean the code in the question (not Daniel's) can't output 55 or "my pet gerbil", and if it makes the computer start to dance and catch fire, you have other issues B-)

Answer (score 1):

Anything can happen, including fireTheMissiles().